Sorting by ID (integer) in phpMyAdmin does not always work, why?
Explain this: When I sort a particular table by ID (unsigned int10) in phpMyAdmin, it correctly lists a couple most recent rows, but then skips to much older rows.
(phpMyAdmin 5.2.0 under MySQL 5.7.39)


...BUT when I sort by date, it works as expected (look at the ID column and never mind the missing DATA from the past week, it's normal)


You have a table where the ID is auto incremented, that is, a record has an id that has the value of the previously created row's ID + 1.
You also have a creation_date field, which has no default value, so we know that whatever value is set there, it was either given during an insert or an update and not inferred from a fallback value (assuming it had no default value previously).
So, the actual creation order of your records is the order of their ids.
As about why creation_date is not in line with it, there are many possible reasons. First of all, it's possible that they were given that way when they were inserted. Or the creation dates were updated. Or some older records were removed and whoever did it, realized it was a mistake, so reinserted them, now having larger IDs than they had prior to their removal.
Given the information you have shared it's impossible to determine what exactly happened, so you will need to look at your logs, older backups, committed scripts, copies of the database, ask around to get more information.
Don't forget to check your code too to see whether there is anything fishy that obfuscates your creation date.
